# how to create a complex masonry layout using bootstrap css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a Web page, which would resemble a particular Power Point slide:

[image]

I have tried to use this approach, but without much success:

```
<div class="container">

    <div id="grids">
        <div>
            <div class="row col-sm-12">
                <div class="graybox col-sm-12" id="1" style="min-height: 50px;"></div>

            </div>

            <div class="row col-sm-12">
            <div class="graybox col-sm-3" id="7" style="min-height: 120px;"></div>
                <div class="graybox col-sm-1" style="min-height: 58px;"></div>


                    <div class="graybox col-sm-1" id="9.0" style="min-height: 20px;"></div>
                    <div class="graybox col-sm-1" id="9.1" style="min-height: 20px;"></div>
                    <div class="graybox col-sm-3" id="9.2" style="min-height: 20px;"></div>
                    <div class="graybox col-sm-3" id="9.3" style="min-height: 120px;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row col-sm-12">
                <div class="graybox col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-3" id="12" style="min-height: 50px;"></div>
                <div class="row col-sm-12">
                    <div class="graybox col-sm-1" id="15" style="min-height: 50px;"></div>
                    <div class="graybox col-sm-1" id="16" style="min-height: 50px;"></div>
                    <div class="graybox col-sm-6" id="17" style="min-height: 50px;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Would anyone know if this type of layout is possible either with bootstrap or some other application of css?

Comment: What you're describing is completely doable with bootstrap, but I think you're having some misunderstandings on the basic framework that constructs bootstrap.

Comment: Do you have some details to share with us? Like, do you need the web page to be responsive or you need it for some specific height or some device(phone, phablet, desktop)? Would the page resemble exactly the photo or you need something more like a powerpoint presentation?

Comment: It does not need to be responsive. It will run in a desktop browser.  It needs to resemble the exact layout shown above. I think, I'm getting pretty close:  https://gist.github.com/eugene-goldberg/be5701376cef0e70545f